# Unity3d+Android, Get path of Assets/Plugins/Android directory

Tags: android, reflection, unity-game-engine

I want to find the path of **Assets/Plugins/Android directory.**

I have tried `string filePath = Application.streamingAssetsPath;`
But it gives path like `jar:file:///mnt/asec/com.cmpny.pkg-2/pkg.apk!/assets`

**Goal:** I want to check programmatically whether a particular jar (abc.jar) file is is present or not. Kindly help me to find that. 
I have placed the jar file here **(AppName\Assets\Plugins\Android\abc.jar)**
I would appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: please help me to resolve that